# checkboxlist styling doesnt works

Tags: asp.net, css, checkboxlist

I have tried all possible ways to replace the default checkbox input button with an interactive gif image , I dont know what i am missing , any help or tutorial will be highly appreciated, below is the css snippet which i m using to apply the checkbox list:

```
#left_columnforSale .accordContent span.chkbox input[type="checkbox"]
{
/*background: url('../images/checkbox.gif') no-repeat;*/
background-color: #800000;
}
```

Sorcecode is :

```
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1" class="chkbox">
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_content$CheckBoxList1$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_content$CheckBoxList1$0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="0 AND 1000" />
    <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_0">0 - £1,000</label>
    <br />
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_content$CheckBoxList1$1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_content$CheckBoxList1$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="1000 AND 2000" />
    <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxList1_1">£1,000 - £2,000</label>
```

and designer view:

```
   <asp:AccordionPane>
               <Header>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CheckListBox
                </Header>
                 <Content>

                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="chkbox">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0 AND 1000">0 - £1,000</asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem Value="1000 AND 2000">£1,000 - £2,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2000 AND 3000">£2,000 - £3,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3000 AND 4000">£3,000 - £4,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4000 AND 5000">£4,000 - £5,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5000 AND 6000">£5,000 - £6,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6000 AND 7000">£6,000 - £7,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="7000 AND 8000">£7,000 - £8,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="8000 AND 9000">£8,000 - £9,000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="9000 AND 10000">£9,000 - £10,000</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:CheckBoxList>

                </Content>

            </asp:AccordionPane>
```

Comment: How does your html list render out as <table> or as <li> ?

Comment: I have included the source code above , its html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with css is not possible/has big limitations since the browser will render default OS inputs no matter if you defined anything or not.

Styling checkboxes, dropdowns and radiobuttons is usually done with help of javascript since this will give you the most consistent results cross browsers.

Here's a way to do it: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: i tried the above example with no success, still cant replace the deafult checkbox input style.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong than - I implemented the same solution many times and it worked always.

Comment: Hi , i have tried this example it works fine: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/   but the problem which i m facing is i am using the check box list in the update panel , therfore when checkbox is clicked the style dissapear, is there any way to recall the selected styles .

Comment: the styles are lost when an asynchronous postback occurs

Comment: Hum from here on you are probably more experienced than me but I would check how your javascript triggers.

Comment: well as far as experience is concerened. i m new in d market nd trying my uni skills nyway , i guess dis is because i have set autopostback=true in my checkboxlist and i cant set that to false coz i need to postback to get the datalist bounded , need to do some adjustment with jquery , either call the style again but that will loose the selected box value ..ahhhh

Comment: might throw anodar question on stackoverflow while trying on my own too

Answer (score 1):

Why not assign a CssClass to your list items?  Might be easier than dealing with the long selector you have now.

Also, your selector looks correct and might be working perfectly.  Setting the background color of a checkbox is one of those inconsistent things across browsers.  See the examples here:  http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes

UPDATE:
If you'd like to test that your css selector is truly working correctly, comment out the background-color line, and add this instead:

```
#left_columnforSale .accordContent span.chkbox input[type="checkbox"]
{
/*background: url('../images/checkbox.gif') no-repeat;
 background-color: #800000;*/
display: none;
}
```

If the checkboxes disappear at least you know the selector is working.

Comment: I even tried with background image and used firebug to invest , if its not getting the image, but everything looks perfect , its just the browser not relplacing the default checkbox with the new image.

Comment: i guess the browser doesnt like rendering the background images fro checkboxlist